# Mapping Gravity form fields to click dimensions

Tags: javascript, clickdimension

I am sending field values from Gravity Forms fields to a Click Dimensions form capture in Microsoft Dynamics 365.

I can successfully get data to map, however, a comma is added to the end of the mapped values.

Here is the code that successfully maps, but adds an extra comma at the end of the value. Are there any Javascript experts that can see why this extra comma is added?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://analytics- au.clickdimensions.com/js/ClickDGravityFormMapper.min.js"> 
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mapper = ClickDGravityFormsMapper(); 
mapper.Init({ 
Url: 'http://analytics-au.clickdimensions.com/forms/h/aEeJunFnIhEGJxocwqLqtM', 
FormId: 'gform_1', 
Mapping: [ 
{ GFId: 'input_1_2', CDId: 'input_2'}, 
{ GFId: 'input_1_1', CDId: 'input_1'}, 
] 
}); 
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the form input is a multi-select or group of checkboxes, or something that allows multiple inputs, it could be because the values of that would be an array.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieStanard. The value is only a text type field for an email address.